# Is there an SVN shorthand for the path to the currently checked out directory?

Tags: svn

I know that there is the ^ shorthand in SVN, so I can do something like this:

```
svn ls ^/
```

This is relative to the repository though. Suppose the repository is structured like this:

```
/project-1/
/project-1/sub-project-a
/project-1/sub-project-b
/project-1/sub-project-b/branches
/project-1/sub-project-b/tags
/project-1/sub-project-b/trunk
/project-2/
...
```

If I have `/project-1/sub-project-b/trunk` checked out, is there a way that I can do operations (such as changing to a branch) relative to the project that I have checked out, not relative to the repository?

For example, if I want to switch to a branch, I need to run:

```
svn switch ^/project-1/sub-project-b/branches/my-branch
```

I want to do something like this:

```
svn switch $CHECKED_OUT_PROJECT/branches/my-branch
```

Is there a way to do that built into SVN or do I need to rely on an environment variable instead?

Answer (score 1):

`../` - shorthand for **parent dir** of current

Thus, for your tree, `/project-1/sub-project-b/branches/my-branch` relative to `/project-1/sub-project-b/trunk` will be `../branches/my-branch`

Comment: This doesn't work for me (SVN version 1.8.9). I get the error '../branches/my-branch' does not appear to be a URL. It seems to treat it like a path local to my wc. Likewise, operations like `svn ls ../` do not work either.